# display plain text php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

after having found the data in a table the function displays the information without missing, with a td tag only the first word which displays the others after the space are not displayed.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Service </th>
                                    <th>Prix</th>
                                    <th >Quantite</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                <tbody>
                  <?php 
               
                    $reqq = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE client = '$clientId' AND dossier = '$dossier' ";
                    $results = $connect->query($reqq);
                  ?>
                                                    <?php if($results->num_rows > 0){ ?>
                           
                            <?php
                            foreach($results as $data){ ?>
                           <?php echo $data['nom']; ?>
                            <tr>
                              
                                <td> <?php print $data['nom']; ?>
                                <td><?= $data['prix']?></td>
                                <td><?= $data['quantite']?></td>
                                <td><a href="facturesanspdf.php?clientName=<?php echo $clientId; ?>&del=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Supprimer</a></td>
                          </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the result is
[image]

Inside the table the last field have **Franchise Procedure** the table only display the first word which is **Franchise**

Help me find the solution please.

Comment: Do you mean the first field `$data['nom']`?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```php
<td> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['nom']); ?> </td>
```

Often, text stored in databases can contains reserved characters in HTML like "<" or "&" which should be replaced by [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

That's what the PHP function [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) was invented for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).